# Query is taking long time to execute in Vertica

Tags: vertica

I have one query to execute which will return the data according to latest date in the table.

Query is like below:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  demo,
  (select * from ACCOUNT where day_id=select max(day_id) from ACCOUNT)ACCOUNT,
  (select * from CUSTOMER where day_id=select max(day_id) from CUSTOMER) CUSTOMER,
  (select * from SBSCRPN where  day_id=select max(day_id) from SBSCRPN) SBSCRPN,
  (select * from TIME where DAY_ID=select max(DAY_ID) from TIME) TIME
   WHERE
  ( CUSTOMER.DAY_ID=ACCOUNT.DAY_ID and CUSTOMER.PARTY_ID=ACCOUNT.PARTY_ID  )
  AND  ( ACCOUNT.DAY_ID=SBSCRPN.DAY_ID and ACCOUNT.ACCT_ID=SBSCRPN.ACCT_ID  )
  AND  ( CUSTOMER.ORG_PARTY_ID=demo.ORG_PARTY_ID  )
  AND  ( TIME.DAY_ID=CUSTOMER.DAY_ID  )
```

this query is taking huge time to execute.
But when am giving the latest date(day_id value) hardcoded in the table, its giving resp within 40-50 sec.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  demo,
  (select * from ACCOUNT where day_id='2021-02-07')ACCOUNT,
  (select * from CUSTOMER where day_id='2021-02-07') CUSTOMER,
  (select * from SBSCRPN where  day_id='2021-02-07') SBSCRPN,
  (select * from TIME where DAY_ID='2021-02-07') from TIME) TIME
  WHERE
  ( CUSTOMER.DAY_ID=ACCOUNT.DAY_ID and CUSTOMER.PARTY_ID=ACCOUNT.PARTY_ID  )
  AND  ( ACCOUNT.DAY_ID=SBSCRPN.DAY_ID and ACCOUNT.ACCT_ID=SBSCRPN.ACCT_ID  )
  AND  ( CUSTOMER.ORG_PARTY_ID=demo.ORG_PARTY_ID  )
  AND  ( TIME.DAY_ID=CUSTOMER.DAY_ID  )
```

So, can anyone please help me to understand why this is taking time whem am using max function in inlineview. Does anyone can help how we can get faster result without harcoded the value in the query.

FYI, few tables contains huge volume of data like below:

```
DEMO;
55624

ACCOUNT;
426415370 ~426M

CUSTOMER;
1827947548 ~1.8B

SBSCRPN;
582688964 ~582M

TIME;
11323
```

Answer (score 0):

From the hard-coded solution you mentioned, calculating max values outside of your query can probably accelerate the query execution. In Vertica, you can [define variables](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/vsql/Variables.htm) and pass them to your SQL queries. For example, `:max` can be used instead of `select max(day_id) from account` in your query where

```
\set max `vsql -At -c "select max(day_id) from account;"`
\echo :max
```

and then you can rewrite your query as follow:

```
select * from account where day_id=:max
```